# custom android library integrated as unity native plugin causes Duplicate Class

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, unity3d-native-plugins

I have built an android library that I try to add in unity. Both the library and the unity project are very basic.

There are these 3 dependencies in the android project

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0
```

In the unity custom mainTemplate.graddle I replicated these dependencies because otherwise, the build was failing with missing classes errors (`error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.)`.

I used the unity jar resolver to resolve dependencies in unity.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1' // Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/MyPluginDependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1' // Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/MyPluginDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0' // Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/MyPluginDependencies.xml:11
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
```

The problem I've been facing now is that all these dependencies clash and there are over 1000 duplicate class errors like this one, from each of those 3 dependencies:

`Duplicate class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintAttribute$1 found in modules constraintlayout-2.1.1-runtime (androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1) and jetified-test-lib-release-runtime (:test-lib-release:)`
where test-lib-release is the android library.

I'm not sure what i am doing wrong and if it's because the library has these classes on the classpath or because my unity config is wrong.
Any help is more than appreciated as i completely run out of ideas.